# Android put contact photo to ListView

Tags: android, listview

i'm writing simple contact reader. in this simple code i have one list view and i want to set photo image to `ListView` image widget but i can not do it.

i get this error:

```
Error:(47, 19) java: no suitable method found for put(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
    method java.util.AbstractMap.put(java.lang.String,android.graphics.Bitmap) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to android.graphics.Bitmap)
    method java.util.HashMap.put(java.lang.String,android.graphics.Bitmap) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to android.graphics.Bitmap)
```

[image]

my problem is set contact photo in `HashMap` and use that in `ListView`. please help me to resolve that.

My Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Cursor cursor = null;
        Context context = getBaseContext();

        String[] from = { "mphoto","id","pname" };
        int[] to = { R.id.mphoto,R.id.pid,R.id.pname};
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mphoto);

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            int contactIdIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID);
            int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
            int phoneNumberIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            int photoIdIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_ID);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            List<HashMap<String, Bitmap>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Bitmap>>();
            do {
                HashMap<String, Bitmap> hm = new HashMap<String,Bitmap>();
                hm.put("id",    cursor.getString(nameIdx));
                hm.put("pname", cursor.getString(phoneNumberIdx));

                bitmap = loadContactPhoto(getContentResolver() , cursor.getLong(contactIdIdx));
                hm.put("mphoto", bitmap);

                aList.add(hm);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);
            ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
    public static Bitmap loadContactPhoto(ContentResolver cr, long  id) {
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
        InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
        if (input == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    }
}
```

My main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

My `listview_layout` XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mphoto"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                />
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pid"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pname"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store(`hm.put("mphoto",bitmap);`) a bitmap in a `HashMap` that stores `String`. Create a sepearate `Hashmap` for Bitmap like

```
HashMap<String,Bitmap>> aPic = new  HashMap<String,Bitmap>>();
```

And insert the pics like using `ID`

```
aPic.put("id", cursor.getString(nameIdx));
aPic.put("pic",bitmap);
```

Comment: thanks sir. i'm update post and i'm paste full code. my problem does not resolve and photo bitmap could not set into listView

Comment: aww.. now you are trying to put string into `Bimap` `HashMap`.. Try to use two different hashmap one for string data and other for `Bitmap`